# How long is one millisecond in the Java world?

Tags: java, performance, time, java-8

I have different reasons for asking this question.

- What was the decision for switching to micro-seconds  in [JSR 310: Date and Time API](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) based on.
- If I measure time with `System.currentTimeMillis()` how can I interpret 1ms? How many method-calls, how many sysouts, how many HashMap#pushs.

I'm absolutely aware of the low scientific standard of this question, but I'd like to have some default values for java operations.

**Edit:**

I was talking about:

```
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
//do random stuff
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-t1);
```

Comment: Default values for what?

Comment: The second question doesn't have "slow scientific standard". It simply doesn't begin to make sense. It's like asking for default values regarding how far one can travel in an hour.

Comment: It's about a millisecond, more or less.

Comment: The duration of 9192631.77 periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the caesium 133 atom.

Comment: @delan "between 1 and 20000 kilometers" wood absolutely fit my needs on a scale from "0 to c*1h"

Comment: (It should be noted that computer "wall time" clocks may run at any rate.  Though clocks that increment at a microsecond granularity are rare, one may increment, say, every 7 microseconds, or only once a millisecond.  And often there is a separate "elapsed time" clock that increments at a higher rate than the "wall time" clock.  Any language standard must assume that clock values will be scaled from an arbitrary computer granularity to the standard's granularity, often with a bit of "fuzziness" in the least-significant bits.)

Comment: What exactly are your "needs"? "0 to c*1h" is a useless answer for any application I can imagine, as it carries virtually no information.

Comment: @delan im talking about [c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A system.currentTimeMillis() milli-second is almost exactly a milli-second except when the system clock is being corrected e.g. using [Network Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) (NTP).  NTP can cause significant leaps in time either forward or backward, but this is rare.  If you want a monotonically increasing clock with more resolution, use System.nanoTime() instead.

> How many method-calls, how many sysouts, how many HashMap#pushs (in 1 ms)

Empty method calls can be eliminated so only sizable method call matter.  What the method does is more important.  You can expect between 1 and 10000 method calls in a milli-second.

sysouts are very dependent on the display and whether it has been paused.  Under normal conditions, you can expect to get 1 to 100 lines of output depending on length and the display in 1 ms.  If the stream is paused for any reason, you might not get any.

HashMap has a put() not push() and you can get around 1000 to 10000 of these in a mill-second.  The problem is you have to have something worth putting, and this usually takes longer.

Answer (score 9):

> What was the decision for switching to micro-seconds in JSR 310: Date and Time API based on.

Modern hardware has had microsecond-precision clocks for quite some time; and it is not new to JSR 310. Consider [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html), which appeared in 1.5 (along with [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--), see below) and has a `MICROSECONDS` value.

> If I measure time with `System.currentTimeMillis()` how can I interpret 1ms?

As accurate as the hardware clock/OS primitive combo allows. There will always be some skew. But unless you do "real" real time (and you shouldn't be doing Java in this case), you will likely never notice.

Note also that this method measures the number of milliseconds since epoch, and *it depends on clock adjustements*. This is unlike `System.nanoTime()`, which relies on an onboard tick counter which never "decrements" with time.

FWIW, `Timer{,Task}` uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` to measure time, while the newer `ScheduledThreadPool` uses `System.nanoTime()`.

As to:

> How many method-calls, how many sysouts, how many HashMap#pushs (in 1 ms)

impossible to tell! Method calls depend on what methods do, sysouts depend on the speed of your stdout (try and sysout on a 9600 baud serial port), pushes depend on memory bus speed/CPU cache etc; you didn't actually expect an accurate answer for *that*, did you?

Answer (score 2):

The answers of Peter Lawrey and fge are so far correct, but I would add following detail considering your statement about microsecond resolution of JSR-310. This new API uses **nanosecond** resolution, not microsecond resolution.

The reason for this is not that clocks based on `System.currentTimeMillis()` might achieve such high degree of precision. No, such clocks just count milliseconds and are sensible for external clock adjustments which can even cause big jumps in time far beyond any subsecond level. The support for nanoseconds is rather motivated to support at maximum nanosecond-based timestamps in many databases (not all!).

It should be noted though that this "precision" is not real-time accuracy, but serves more for avoiding duplicated timestamps (which are often created via mixed clock and counter mechanisms - not measuring scientifically accurate real-time). Such database timestamps are often used as primary keys by some people - therefore their requirement for a non-duplicate monotonically increasing timestamp).

The alternative `System.nanoTime()` is supposed and designed to show better monotonically increasing behaviour although I would not bet my life on that in some multi-core environments. But here you indeed get nanosecond-like differences between timestamps so JSR-310 can give at least calculatory support via classes like `java.time.Duration` (but again not necessarily scientifically accurate nanosecond differences).